# Getting Net::Telnet to send a character at a time?

Tags: ruby, telnet

I am trying to use Net::Telnet to login to some appliances.  For the login prompt, the device requires a single character at a time for the login and password prompt.  Ruby sends the whole username at once.  Is there a way to set it to send a single character at a time?

Here is my script:

```
require 'net/telnet'
options = Hash.new
ipaddr = '10.160.64.103'

date = Time.new.strftime('-%H.%M.%S')

basedir = '.'

files = Dir.glob("#{ipaddr}*.log")

if files.size >= 0
  File.delete(files[0])
end

file = File.new("#{ipaddr}-telnet#{date}.log", "w")

tn = Net::Telnet::new("Host"       => ipaddr,
                      "Output_log" => "#{ipaddr}-telnet#{date}.log",
                      "Dump_log"   => "dump.log",
                      "Prompt"     => /->\z/ )

options["Name"]           ||= "anonymous"
options["Password"]       ||= "********"

tn.login(options) { |c| print c }

tn.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do it so simply as the login method, but following the source for `login`, we can do something similar:

```
prompt = /->\z/
login_prompt = /[Ll]ogin[: ]*\z/
password_prompt = /[Pp]ass(?:word|phrase)[: ]*\z/

# wait until we've seen a login prompt
tn.waitfor(login_prompt){|c| print c }
# print each user character, newline; wait for password prompt
(user+"\n").each_char{|c| tn.print(c) }
tn.waitfor(password_prompt){|c| print c }
# print each pass character, newline; wait for normal prompt
(pass+"\n").each_char{|c| tn.print(c) }
tn.waitfor(prompt){|c| print c }
```

(Note that I didn't test this)

Comment: Thanks! that worked! with one modification: add a sleep after the print or else, depending on the speed of the computer, it will send a couple letters in the same packet